# How to say "I had cleaned at home"?

Tags: grammar, idioms, past-tense, past-perfect

I can't find a similar sentence in Google. I'm trying to say that I already have done cleaning in my apartments and in the process of it I ... etc. Is "A couple months ago, we had cleaned at the home." correct? Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? If the cleaning is done, it cannot also be in process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to say that you cleaned two months ago:

> I cleaned the house a couple of months ago.

But if you want to say that something happened immediately after you cleaned your house you could use the word "just":

> I had **just** cleaned my house when my friend arrived.

You mentioned "already". If this is important you could say:

> I had **already** cleaned the apartment when he called to remind me to do
>   it.

You also mentioned "in the process". If something happened during the cleaning you would say:

> I was cleaning my house when I remembered my appointment.

or

> I found my keys while cleaning my house.

Answer (score 0):

First : `at home`, instead of `at the home`. Or `at the house` instead of `at the home`.

With the informations you've given here,  I would simply use `A couple of months ago, I cleaned the house` or if you want to insist on the fact that you've already done the cleaning, `A couple of months ago, I did clean my home`.

[Here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) is a page with all the uses of the past perfect :

Does what you want to say match any of the cases of this page?

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you got **rid of the dust from your house** or maybe **vacuumed your house** if you're using a vacuum cleaner.

According to *thefreedictionary*:

> Definition(vacuum): to clean (something) with a vacuum cleaner

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vacuumed